# Remove an element from a JSON file in a test method

Tags: c#, json, file, testing

I have a JSON File, as below, and I would like to remove a line/element of this, specifically the "FinanceDetails[LoanAmount]". How do I write this in C#.

```
"IntegratorID": "e20a5569-8e63-42ca-9f33-872d826276d0",
  "CorrelationID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "ProposalID": 0,
  "Stage": "DECISION",
  "Request": "SendProposal",
  "PropertyValues": {
    "ExternalReference": "Integrator Reference",
    "ProposalType": "Private Individual",
    "Dealer[DealerID]": "9344",
    "FinanceDetails[Type]": "PCP",
    "FinanceDetails[CashDeposit]": "111",
    "FinanceDetails[Settlement]": "11",
    "FinanceDetails[PartExchange]": "22",
    "FinanceDetails[Term]": "72",
    "FinanceDetails[APR]": "12.9",
    "FinanceDetails[LoanAmount]": "0",
    "FinanceDetails[AnnualMileage]": "40000"
}
```

This is what I currently have, but not working.

```
public static void RemoveLineRequest(string fieldName)
{
    string sendProposalRequestSuccess = File.ReadAllText(sendProposalJSONFile);
    dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sendProposalRequestSuccess);
    string output = jsonObj["PropertyValues"][fieldName];
    string finaloutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(output, Formatting.Indented);
    File.WriteAllText(sendProposalJSONFile, finaloutput);
}
```

Comment: try `delete jsonObj["PropertyValues"]["FinanceDetails[LoanAmount]"]`;

Comment: If you weren't doing this dynamically you could just remove the property from your model.

Answer (score 1):

Do not deserialize to `dynamic`, use [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_linq_jobject.htm) (see the 

[Modifying JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ModifyJson.htm) doc):

```cs
var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(sendProposalRequestSuccess);
var propValues = (JObject)jsonObject["PropertyValues"];
propValues.Remove("FinanceDetails[LoanAmount]");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `jObjProperty.Remove()`

```
public static void RemoveLineRequest(string fieldName, string sendProposalJSONFile)
{
    string sendProposalRequestSuccess = File.ReadAllText(sendProposalJSONFile);
    var jObj = JObject.Parse(sendProposalRequestSuccess);
    var jObjProperty = (JObject)jObj.SelectToken("PropertyValues");
    jObjProperty.Property(fieldName).Remove();
    File.WriteAllText(sendProposalJSONFile, jObj.ToString());
}
```